# Parameter injection not working in BigQuery Vertex AI notebook for WEEK(WEEKDAY)

Tags: google-bigquery, jupyter-notebook, google-cloud-vertex-ai

I'm using a Vertex AI notebook, running BigQuery IPython magics and injecting parameters.

```py
params = {"day_of_week": "WEDNESDAY"}
```

```sql
%%bigquery sales_df --project $project_id --params $params

SELECT created_date, num_sales
FROM sales
WHERE DATE_DIFF(created_date, "2023-01-01", WEEK(@day_of_week)) BETWEEN -12 and 11
```

I'd expect this to work but it doesn't because `WEEK` expects a `WEEKDAY` argument ([BQ docs](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions#date_diff)). Hardcoding it as `WEEK(WEDNESDAY)` works but the parameter injection doesn't because it adds quotes around the string, effectively compiling it as `WEEK("WEDNESDAY")`.

Is there any workaround here? I can't find a BQ method that turns a string weekday (`"WEDNESDAY"`) into the day of week enum (`WEDNESDAY`).

UPDATE: I have raised this as a BigQuery feature request -https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/266201211.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try [a dynamic SQL](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/procedural-language#execute_immediate) in your BigQuery magic.

```py
params = {"day_of_week": "WEDNESDAY"}

%%bigquery sales_df --project $project_id --params $params
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
  SELECT created_date, num_sales
  FROM sales
  WHERE DATE_DIFF(created_date, "2023-01-01", WEEK(%s)) BETWEEN -12 and 11
""", @day_of_week);
```

below is a working example I've tried.

```py
%%bigquery --project your-project-id --params {"day_of_week": "WEDNESDAY"}
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE FORMAT("""
  SELECT DATE_DIFF(CURRENT_DATE, "2023-01-01", WEEK(%s)) BETWEEN -12 and 11
""", @day_of_week)
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Ugly but it works and I doubt there's a better way.

Comment: I agree. I'll take another look at it and update you if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: For me this seems like a missing feature of BQ - they need to give users a way to convert `"WEDNESDAY"` to `WEDNESDAY`

Comment: I have raised this as a BigQuery feature request -https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/266201211.